# Loopback upsert with addition

Tags: mysql, orm, loopbackjs

I'm trying to `upsert` a database table with loopback. The raw query is

```
insert into all_inventory (sku, qty, regal, fach, skuRegalFach)
values (?, 1, ?, ?, ?) 
on duplicate key update 
   qty = qty + 1, 
   regal = values(regal), 
   fach = values(fach)
```

Is there any way to do this with loopback?

Currently I'm facing two problems.

I get:

> ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '22323' for key
>   'all_inventory_SkuRegalFach_uindex'

Because loopback doesn't seem to be able to handle the key correctly.

And I have no idea how to tell loopback to add 1 to the qty field instead of just overriding it with the new value.

I have it working with a raw query right now,

```
let ds = Inventory.dataSource,
    values = [sku, regal, fach, sku + regal + fach],
    sql = `insert into all_inventory (sku, qty, regal, fach, skuRegalFach) values (?, 1, ?, ?, ?) on duplicate key update qty = qty + 1, regal = values(regal), fach = values(fach)`
ds.connector.query(sql, values, (err, products) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    cb(null, products);
});
```

Is there a way to do this with loopback's ORM?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd use a find filter. Either findById or find with an appropriate filter.

If you get a result, then it exists. You can modify qty and then store it. If it doesn't exist, then you just create it.